# How to see that bios is trying to boot from some drive but fails nowadays?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, motherboard

I have a `MSI PRO H610M-E DDR4` motherboard with `MSI Click BIOS 5` on it. I have plugged several HDDs into it and it sees them. One of the disks (should be) bootable.

Unfortunately, the system doesn't boot and doesn't show any errors. On boot, it just goes to BIOS setup screen.

Also, I don't see boot priority per each disk. I see just order of TYPES of boot, but not an order of individual disks

[image]

Is it possible to make BIOS to try to boot from a given disk and give explicit error message if it failed? Or is it possible to know, why did it decided to to boot from this given disk?

---

I have booted Ubuntu from flash drive, I was able to see all of my drives including boot one, which was

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00043db7

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *         2048 612575231 612573184 292.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdd2       612577278 625141759  12564482     6G  5 Extended
/dev/sdd5       612577280 625141759  12564480     6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I have reinstalled grub on it's boot sector, but this didn't help.

Comment: Do you need Legacy enabled? Hard to believe in 2023. Setting it to "UEFY only" will greatly simplify it. You don't need Legacy unless installing obsolete OSes like Windows XP which you couldn't anyway because such hardware won't support it. Then you need to understand the UEFI mode boot process that relies on bootloaders in an ESP of which only ONE is needed regardless the amount of physical drives. "Boot from a given disk" is then nonsensical.

Comment: Its likely that the OS requires secure boot to be enabled, but this is disabled, and as such pushes you to the BIOS as a failsafe.

Comment: @LPChip I don't think that's how it works. Secure Boot should be optional and disabling it shouldn't prevent anything from booting. At worst it would make the bootloader angry, but it would be booted.

Comment: @gronostaj my experience told me that if Windows Bootloader is the primary boot partition on a drive, and it was installed with secure boot enabled, disabling it, will fail the bootloader to be detected. Some BIOSes will simply give an error, others will show the BIOS screen. The latter seems to always happen with modern systems nowadays. Also, Windows 11 requires secure boot, and altough I have not tested it, I would not be surprised if the bootloader pushes you to the BIOS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't install anything, I have a drive, which I want to boot from. Since I don't remember what is it, I need to configure maximally broad option.

Comment: @Dims Can't you boot from another drive that works, and just keep this drive attached so you can at least see what's on the drive?

Comment: @LPChip see the update: I did it. The drive looks ok, it is visible by fdisk, I can mount it and browse files. I think that "clever" BIOS just doesn't try to boot from it. At least, I don't see any signs, that BIOS tries it.